# How to render a partial view that deals with its own controller within another view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and I wanna render a partial view in a popup within a view, but I wondering how to provide the partial view's model.

```
<div id="enumsDialog" class="dialog">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Enumeration/List.cshtml", [it needs a modal here])
</div>
```

In another words, I want the partial view to deal with its own controller.

How to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to render a partial view whose action/data comes from a different controller, then you will probably want to use the RenderAction method:

```
@Html.Action("MyAction", "MyController")
```

If you are wanting to render a partial view with data from your current viewmodel (without having to make another request of your application), then use the RenderPartial method:

```
@Html.Partial("NameOfView", Model.WhateverYouArePassing)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is this one:

```
public class EnumerationController : Controller {

    // other actions...

    public ActionResult List(){
        // TODO: var model = retrieve-your-model-here
        return PartialView(model);
        // using "PartialView" instead of "View" method ensures this action isn't 
        // responsible from direct requests
        // Also you can use "PartialViewResult" class as a return-type instead
        // of "ActionResult" in method, like "List2()" method below:
    }

    public PartialViewResult List2(){
        // TODO: var model = retrieve-your-model-here
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

and in `.cshtml` file:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("List", "Enumeration");}
// or:
@Html.Action("List", "Enumeration")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked well, but the problem is that when any action is taken by the partial view, it causes rendering the whole page not just the popup content. In another words, I wanna simulate an update panel functionality. Is it possible in MVC ?

Comment: Do you mean that when you are rendering the partial-view, the full html-code (include layout) renders? or anything else? -my English is not good, I'm sorry, please explain more your purpose- thanks